# Turn drone in given angle (left or right turn)

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0, ardrone-autonomy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy!

Is there any -  already developed - way to turn my flying parrot ardrone 2.0 ? I can't find any info about this.
I want a topic or service, that will turn my drone for example 90 degrees left, if i type the command with the "90" parameter.

Please help me, it is urgent!!!
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272039/turn-drone-in-given-angle-(left-or-right-turn)/) by [Steve_RosUsr](https://answers.ros.org/users/32021/steve_rosusr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-02**:
Have you looked at the docs? https://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html

**Comment by [Steve_RosUsr](https://answers.ros.org/users/32021/steve_rosusr/) on 2017-10-04**:
Yes, i did. But as you can see in the title of the post, i want to give an **angle** as parameter, not speed value.

Any useful answers will be appreciated.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-04**:
Well, the title doesn't say that exactly but I did give you an alternative to `ardrone_autonomy` (actually it uses `ardrone_autonomy`) which may do what you want. Hopefully it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no services or topics to do this using `ardrone_autonomy` that I have seen. You either have to develop it yourself or you can use `tum_ardrone` which is based on `ardrone_autonomy`. It includes a [GUI](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone#drone_gui) in which you can send commands similar to how you want to send them. An example from the README,

> `goto [doube x] [double y] [double z] [double yaw]`
>
> flies to position (x,y,z yaw), relative to current reference point.
> blocks until target is reached according to set parameters

So, you would type `goto 0 0 0 90.0` in order to rotate 90 degrees. You can also write flight paths as a `.txt` file and load them from the GUI and have it execute them. If you want to do this via a node you may have to look at their code and see how they did this and copy it.

Here are the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone) and entry on the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1